# Getting marginal distribution from joint distribution

Tags: probability

While reading a academic paper in Economics, I found the authors get a marginal distribution from a joint distribution as following:

$1$. Joint distribution

$$G_n(c_1, c_2)=\Pr[C_{1n} < c_1, C_{2n} < c_2] = 1-e^{-\Phi_n c_1^\theta} - \Phi_n c_1^\theta e^{-\Phi_n c_2^\theta}, \qquad 0 \leq c_1 \leq c_2 < \infty.$$

$2$. Marginal distribution

$$G_{1n}(c1)=\Pr[C_{1n}<c_{1}]=\lim_{c_{2}\rightarrow\infty}G_n(c_1,c_2)= 1-e^{-\Phi_n c_1^\theta}$$

However,as far as I know, to get a marginal distribution of $c_1$ from a joint distribution of $c_1$ and $c_2$, I would have to take integral with respect to $c_2$, with the range of ($c_1$,$\infty$). At this point, I am really lost and cannot proceed. Is there anyone could help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get the marginal ***density*** you need to integrate the joint density:
$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy$$

To get the marginal ***distribution*** you just need to take the limit:

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y)$$

$$F_X(x) = P(X \le x) = P(X \le x , Y \le \infty)=F_{X,Y}(x,\infty)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I realize it.